# React is not rendering if state is set in constructor by a function

Tags: reactjs, function, constructor, state, render

I'm trying to initiate the page according to user login status. For this purpose I tried to set initial state by a function but it's not updating view after api call completed.
Currenty I see Part 3 when codes are executed.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { API_BASE_URL } from './constants/apiConstants';

    export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            loginStatus: this.loginUpdate(),
        }
    }

    loginUpdate(){
        let token = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN");

        let tmpStatus = token!==""?true:false;

        if(tmpStatus){
            const payload = {
                "token": token
            }
    
            axios.post(API_BASE_URL + 'loginCheck', payload)
                .then((response) => {
                    tmpStatus=response.data.response;
                    return tmpStatus;
                });
        }else{
            return tmpStatus;
        }

        return null;
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.state.loginStatus===true &&
                    <p>Part 1</p>
                }

                {this.state.loginStatus===false &&
                    <p>Part 2</p>
                }

                {this.state.loginStatus===null &&
                    <p>Part 3</p>
                }
                </>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

> You should update the state variable inside the `then callback` of Axios. You have an API call in `loginUpdate function` but the problem is that your `HTML` renders first and then your `API` response comes. Also, you missed `return` statement before `Axios` but putting that will also not resolved your issue.

**Solution:**

> You should set your state variable inside the `then callback`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_BASE_URL } from './constants/apiConstants';

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        loginStatus: localStorage.getItem("TOKEN") !== '' ? true : false,
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.loginUpdate();
}

loginUpdate(){
    let token = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN");

    let tmpStatus = token!==""?true:false;

    if(tmpStatus){
        const payload = {
            "token": token
        }

        axios.post(API_BASE_URL + 'loginCheck', payload)
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({ loginStatus: response.data.response });
         });
    }else{
        return tmpStatus;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Indeed returning always true was a mistake... And I updated the answer as you recommended as well. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You should return axios result as well.

```
    return axios.post(API_BASE_URL + 'loginCheck', payload)
            .then((response) => {
                tmpStatus=response.data.response;
                return tmpStatus;
            });
```

Comment: you still missed `return` for the axios. not only inside then(...), but also you should return the whole axios.

Answer (score 0):

I was able resolve the issue with the following approach:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_BASE_URL } from './constants/apiConstants';
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        loginStatus: null,
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.loginUpdate();
}

loginUpdate(){
    let token = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN");

    let tmpStatus = token!==""?true:false;

    if(tmpStatus){
        const payload = {
            "token": token
        }

        axios.post(API_BASE_URL + 'giris/kontrol', payload)
            .then((response) => {
                tmpStatus=response.data.response;
                this.setState({loginStatus:tmpStatus});
            });
    }else{
        this.setState({loginStatus:tmpStatus});
    }
  }

render() {
    return (
        <>
            {this.state.loginStatus===true &&
                <p>Part 1</p>
            }

            {this.state.loginStatus===false &&
                <p>Part 2</p>
            }

            {this.state.loginStatus===null &&
                <p>Part 3</p>
            }
            </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, why are you setting loginStatus as true always in `this.setState({loginStatus:true});` Also better if you call loginUpdate function in componentDidMount. You can check my answer.

Comment: Updated this.setState({loginStatus:tmpStatus}); and added componentDidMount function as well... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While constructor is running, "loginStatus" state is set to the first result of your method "loginUpdate()", which is "null". When the method "loginUpdate()" is called in constructor, it starts the axios, but not wait for the answer of axios. It will be running as async. After the "null" value is set, constructor is finished its work. So, the result of axios will never be used.

For this reason, you should use this.setState() function when axios result is taken. Also, you should not use the method in constructor. Therefore, if you put the method in "componentDidMount" and use setState function after the result is taken on axios, you will get the result expected. In setState function you should set "loginStatus" with axios response.